# substr not working correctly?

Tags: php

I am creating a forum, and currently working on the bbCode section. All the BBCode works, but I am also implementing an emoticon system. The syntax looks like this: [e]:)[/e]

I made this string for testing purposes:

```
[b]hello world[/b] [i]i am having fun[/i] [e]:)[/e] how are you doing today?! <3[color=blue]:D[/color]
```

And it is returning something that is not what I want. Here is what it is returning:

```
:)[/e] how are you doing today?! <3[color=bl
```

This is my code:

```
function bbCode($str) {
     if (strpos($str, '[e]')!==false && strpos($str, '[/e]')!==false) {
          $f = strpos($str, '[e]') + 3;
          $s = strpos($str, '[/e]');
          $emote = substr($str, $f, $s);
     }
     return $emote;
}
```

Note that $f and $s are returning the correct positions, 45 and 47, but the substr is not cutting my string correctly. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: The length of the selected string looks suspiciously related to the end index found: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) for the 3rd parameter :D

Comment: PHP has a [BBCode extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php). And you need to open the function with an opening curly brace, `{`.

Answer (score 2):

"string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )

Returns the portion of string specified by the start **and length** parameters."

```
$emote = substr($str, $f, $s - $f);
```

Comment: or is it `1 + $s - $f`?

Comment: Aw, you beat me! +1 for being fast =)

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of substr is supposed to be the length of the string you wish to extract. Change it to `substr($str, $f, $s - $f);`

Official documentation can be found here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php